# Switch statement with enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I hope someone can direct me to the right direction.

I have the below code in enum with department names and their codes. I want to be able to print the departments' full names with their descriptions on the screen. I want to accomplish that by using a switch statement, but I am unsure where to place the switch statement.

```
enum DepartmentName {
     FINANCE        ("FIN")
   , SALES          ("SAL")
   , PAYROLL        ("PYR")
   , LOGISTIC       ("LGT")
   ;

    private final String department;

    DepartmentName(String abbr) {
        department = abbr;
    }

    public String getDepartmentCode() {return department;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The department name is " + getDepartmentCode();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume your real code has a `)` after `"LGT"`? (Looks like dasblinkenlight also assumes that, as he just updated the question code to add it.)

Comment: Why would you use a switch statement? If you want each enum to have a department full name, then add it as a field of the enum, as you're doing with the department code. Or do you mean that the name of the enum (FINANCE, for example) is the department's full name? Enums have a name() method, which returns their name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to be able to print the departments' full names with their descriptions on the screen.

You need to associate the full name with each `enum` value. The simplest way of doing it is to add a `description` member to the `enum`:

```
enum DepartmentName {
     FINANCE        ("FIN", "Finance")
   , SALES          ("SAL", "Sales")
   , PAYROLL        ("PYR", "Payroll")
   , LOGISTIC       ("LGT", "Logistic")
   ;

    private final String department;
    private final String description;

    DepartmentName(String abbr, String full) {
        department = abbr;
        description = full;
    }

    public String getDepartmentCode() {return department;}

    public String getDescription() {return description;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The department name is " + getDepartmentCode();
    }
}
```

> I want to accomplish that by using a switch statement

That would be a wrong way of doing that, because the association with the name would be external to the `enum` (i.e. no longer be encapsulated). The consequence of this is that each time you add a new `enum` member, all your `switches` that depend on that `enum` would need to change. Moreover, the compiler would not be able to help you catch places where you missed the new `enum` value.

Answer (score 1):

To String should be following:

```
public String toString() {
    switch (this) {
        case FINANCE:
            return "finance";
        case SALES:
            return "sales";
        case PAYROLL:
            return "payroll";
        ... // and so on
    }
    return this.name();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It helped a lot to understand.